# Query a Document for its _id and a nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my mongoDB express application I have the following model:

```
const pricelistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    pricelist_rows: [{
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        product_id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'products',
            required: true,
        },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    }],
});
```

Using mongoose I want to query the pricelist _id ( auto-generated ) and the product_id nested in the product_rows to retrieve the prices of a product. Like so:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6502bb5b762298a2354779da", --->myPricelistVariable
        "name": "Base",
        "created_at": "2023-09-14T09:48:38.570Z",
        "pricelist_rows": {
            "_id": "6502bb63762298a2354779e0",
            "product_id": "6502bb4f762298a2354779d8", --->myProductVariable
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 1.24
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "6502bb5b762298a2354779da",
        "name": "Base",
        "created_at": "2023-09-14T09:48:38.570Z",
        "pricelist_rows": {
            "_id": "65104ff575af74cd14e3bd8f",
            "product_id": "6502bb4f762298a2354779d8",
            "price": 1.1,
            "quantity": 1,
        }
    }
  }
]
```

Using [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is not working as it would retrive only 1 element (the first) in case I have more than 1 product_id in my product_rows array.
I attempted to use aggregate and $unwind but it's returning an empty array. What should I do to retrive the data?

```
const pricelist = await Pricelist.aggregate([
                          { $unwind: '$pricelist_rows' },
                          { $match: { _id: *myPricelistVariable*, 'pricelist_rows.product_id': *myProductVariable* } }
                        ]);
```

Comment: are your myPricelistVariable and myProductVariable strings or ObjectIDs . if they are strings you might need to convert them to ObjectID

Comment: also i believe that if u filter out the myPricelistVariable first it would be more efficient since lesser unwinds to do
https://mongoplayground.net/p/HJNCywFJnoT

Comment: The are both ObjectID, in my controller i am already checking if the type is correct  and indeed it is

Comment: hmm not sure whats going wrong then. does the playground link look similar to yours

Comment: Yes, the playground is the exact replica, though here still not working... i copied and pasted your playground and still not returning data..

Comment: how did u convert the myPricelistVariable to ObjectID type

Comment: @cmgchess. Just found the solution to the problem... my object_id validator was not doing his job, when i converted the myProductIdVariable using const productIdObject = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(product_id); (same as i did with myPricelistVariable) the query works as per your example. thanks a lot man!

Comment: cool u may post the answer with ur fix

Answer (score 1):

The aggregate / unwind method is the correct one.

```
const prices = await Pricelist.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
        _id: basePricelist
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$pricelist_rows"
    },
    {
        $match: {
        "pricelist_rows.product_id": productId
        }
    }
])
```

I did not convert productId (passed as a string parameter ) to a mongoose ObjectId and that lead (wrong) empty array returned